# Get value of component from custom ASP.Net localisation resource provider

Tags: asp.net, localization

We are using a custom localisation resource provider to get localisation resource values for ASP.Net components. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.iresourceprovider.aspx

If I have a label like:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelHello" runat="server" Text="Hello you" meta:resourcekey="LabelHelloResource1"></asp:Label>
```

I would like to get the "Text" value (Hello you) from that label in the CustomResourceProvider function "GetObject".

Is this or something similar possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, that you chech in-deep article on this topic: [ASP.NET 2.0 Localization Features: A Fresh Approach to Localizing Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379546%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).